# Google Sheets Api authentication for Discord.js without .json

Tags: node.js, google-api, discord.js

I am using a Discord bot to access a Google Sheets document.  I have created a Google Service Account and provided this Service Account access to the Sheets document and generated the private key `.json` file.  I have created a command in my bot to find records in the sheet.  This appears to be working fine when I run the bot locally (in or out of Debug mode).  I assume this is because the `.json` configuration is part of the project.

I don't want to check the `.json` file into the repository (because that's not appropriate anyway).  I'm also not 100% sure the functionality would work if I were to check it into the repository, and because of this I also don't want to check it in.

What is an alternate way to authenticate without putting the 10 new values from the private key `.json` into the `.env` file (and subsequently adding them to Heroku).

**Current code (excerpt):**

```
const { google } = requires('googleapis');    

async run(message, searchText) 
{
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
         keyFile : "credentials.json",
         scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    });

    // create client instance for auth
    const client = await auth.getClient();

    // create instance of google sheets api
    const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: client});

   /* other code here */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I added my `.json` file to an environment variable, and then read that environment variable into a `JSON.parse()` function and passed it into the `credentials` property of `GoogleAuth`.  Looks something like this:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
     credentials: JSON.parse(credentials_env_variable),
     scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
});
```